# Misturar bibliotecas Javascript em um projeto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, angularjs

Gostaria de saber se não é uma boa prática carregar várias bibliotecas Javascript diferentes em uma aplicação.

Por exemplo, o projeto tem um prazo X para entrega, porém deveria ser feito em AngularJS mas o desenvolvedor conhece mais sobre jQuery o que torna mais rápido o desenvolvimento do projeto. Com o passar do tempo adquire conhecimentos sobre as `directivas` do AngularJS e resolve incluir essa biblioteca no código fonte junto com o jQuery e substituindo determinada regra de negócio para o layout que poderia fazer com jQuery e agora implementou com o AngularJS.

Até quando é recomendável fazer essa prática? Por que não fazer tudo utilizando AngularJS ou outra biblioteca? Algum artigo que aborde sobre isso ou uma resposta com bons argumentos sobre isso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Angular é um framework, jQuery é uma bilioteca. Os dois podem conviver num mesmo projeto tranquilamente.

O problema é se você quiser usar dois frameworks ou duas bibliotecas que cumprem o mesmo objetivo.

Por exemplo, as combinações abaixo não seriam recomendadas:

- Jquery e Zepto
- Angular e Ember
- Google Maps e Leaflet

Você pode até ver projetos que fazem esse tipo de combinação, mas isso é um sinal que provavelmente o resto do código deve ser bem bagunçado e de difícil manutenção.

> **Edit:**
>
> Só para complementar: na prática, um projeto web em produção costuma
>   usar dezenas (em alguns casos, até centenas) de bibliotecas ao mesmo
>   tempo. Um framework nada mais é do que uma coleção de bibliotecas
>   feitas para trabalhar em conjunto.
>
> É recomendável que você use um gerenciador de pacotes para seu
>   projeto, como o Bower, para manter as suas bibliotecas organizadas.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, muito clara. Zepto, e Leaflet não conhecia a respeito deles.

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian Só adicionando, Angular faz uso do jQuery. Junto com o Angular, vem uma lib chamada jQueryLite, que é uma versão reduzida do jQuery. Se no seu HTML você incluir o jQuery completo **antes** do Angular, o Angular fará uso do jQuery completo, ao invés do jQueryLite.

Comment: Interessante @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira

Comment: Bem colocado, @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira. Eu particularmente não sou usuário do Angular e não conheço muito a fundo. No caso de frameworks prefiro o Ember ou, dependendo do projeto, algo mais "light" como o Backbone (que também usa jQuery como uma das suas dependências).

Comment: Excelente discussão, estava passando pelo mesmo "dilema" mas depois de algumas pesquisas vi que cada um tem seu uso específico, e bem separados como framework e lib... aplicações mais ricas para os usuários..

Answer (score 3):

*Iria abrir um tópico parecido por isso vou deixar aqui minha opinião.*

Isso depende muito dos frameworks envolvidos.

**Jquery + Angular: Não é uma boa prática**

O **angular** é um framework reativo. Internamente ele usa um timeout que fica olhando as variáveis de escopo. Sempre que algo muda ele atualiza a página com o conteúdo. Você não acessa o DOM diretamente e usa do conceito ***single page*** o que melhora consideravelmente a performance da aplicação.

O **jquery** possui uma abordagem totalmente diferente. Ela usa acesso a DOM para recuperar e setar informações. Esse acesso não é recomendável devido a perda de performance da aplicação. Não vou entrar no mérito de como funciona porque estaria tratando de um assunto não voltado ao tópico.

**React + Jquery: Não é uma boa prática**

O **react** é um framework orientado a templates. Também possui o conceito de ***single page*** e é reativo como o angular. Não considero uma boa prática justamente porque o próprio framework já dispõe de tudo que você precisa. Além do que é mais leve que o angular pois seu core é menor. Por isso não faz sentido incluir outro framework js para fazer algo que o react já faz.

**React + Angular: Não é uma boa prática**

Mesmo ambos sendo reativos e usando conceito ***single page*** a estrutura e forma de desenvolvimento é diferente. Misturar ambos pode gerar uma salada de fruta que mais irá confundir do que ajudar. Vale lembrar que o desenvolvimento com angular particularmente é mais rápido e possui mais recursos. Entretanto o react é mais leve além de ser utilizado e mantido pelo facebook. Nem preciso me aprofundar mais para afirmar que também é uma boa opção.

**Em resumo**

Esses são alguns dos principais frameworks disponíveis no mercado. Esses que citei são muito utilizados na comunidade front-end, possuem documentação boa com vários exemplos disponíveis na net. Logo, não tem o porque usar mais de um.

Sei como funciona o mercado de TI. Pressão por entregas e etc. Mais mudar o curso do projeto porque alguém não conhece do recurso usado é um problema de equipe. Se você é programador tem a obrigação de saber todas as tecnologias usadas pela equipe justamente para não ter esse tipo de problema. Agora se é um feijão com arroz e a empresa aceita é porque a empresa não está focada na qualidade de código fonte e posteriormente na qualidade do projeto para o cliente.